# React-router: при переходе сразу к вложенному роуту не отрабатывает компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router

Начал использовать **react + react-router + express + Webpack**.

Сервер по любому роуту отдаёт статический html. 
К этому html подключаю скрипт.

Этот роутинг работает отлично, если переходить по внутренним ссылкам/кнопкам внутри компонентов или делать push в историю. То есть от одного компонента к новому роуту переходит нормально.

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={StartPage}> 
      <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/> 
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/> 
      <Route path="app" component={App}>
        <Route path="projects" component={Projects}/> 
        <Route path=":user" component={Home}/> 
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Но стоит мне набрать самому в url'e: `'app/projects'` или `'app/Rumata'` (`http://localhost:1330/app/projects`), например – соответствующие дочерние компоненты внутри **app** никогда не отрабатывают. 
Браузер говорит:

> bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Хотя в остальном весь мой реакт нормально работает. Ошибка возникала и до перехода на вебпак, и с ним.

При этом с компонентами "Signup" или "Login" и с самим "App" таких проблем нет. Я могу просто ввести соответствующий url сразу, и они отрендерятся.

UPD: При попытке отладить заметил, что если вписать `http://localhost:1330/app/projects`, то и к bundle.js обращение идёт  `/app/build/bundle.js.` вместо `/build/bundle.js`, то есть уже из другой, неправильной директории.
Как исправить?

В чём заключается проблема? Не знаю: роутер виноват или же на сервере нужно что-то менять.

Answer (score 1):

Смехотворно, но достаточно подправить пути в index.html, поставив слэши перед путями. Это исправит проблему. 
Иначе стили и bundle будут искаться относительного того места, куда мы "зароутились".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

<script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

можете так же изменить в webpack конфиге в output добавить ublicPath: '/'